# Necessary Condition for $C^{2}$ Regularity of this Function

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

If I define
$$u(x,t):=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{B(x,t)}\frac{f(y,t-|x-y|)}{|x-y|}\;dy$$
for $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\times(0,\infty)$, what regularity of $f$ is required so that $u$ is at least $C^{2}$ (jointly in $(x,t))$?  I'm sure most people will recognize this as the solution of $u_{tt}-\Delta u=f$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}\times(0,\infty)$ with $0$ initial data.

It is obvious that something like $f\in C^{2}$ is *sufficient*.  As for being necessary, I doubt this, but certainly $f$ being continuous is.  Is there some way through a combination of proof/counter-examples to come up with the sharpest regularity requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula can thought of as a weighted average over the past light cone $C_{x,t}=\{(y,s):|x-y|=t-s,\,s<t\}$ for a function $f$ that is supported in $\{t\geq0\}$. We choose $f$ so that it vanishes near the $t$-axis, and its restriction to any of the cones $C_{0,t}$ is smooth. Then the regularity of $u(0,t)$ as a function of $t$ is determined by how $f$ varies from one cone to another. So one can produce, for instance, $f$ in $C^{1,1}$ with $u\not\in C^2$.